# REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL not working, why?

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

```
a = load '/text.log' using TextLoader() as line:chararray;
b = foreach a generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'projectVersion:[^\t]*');
c = group b by $0;
d = foreach c generate group, COUNT(b);
dump d;
```

above is my script, and my sample data is somewhat like..

```
projectName:test    logType:test    logSource:test  logBody:test
```

and I got this result

```
(,0)
```

I looked up Pig API, it says REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL will return empty tuple if pattern doesn't match, but obviously there exists that pattern. so I tried more simpler task..

```
b = foreach a generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'projectVersion');
```

and also tried

```
b = foreach a generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'p');
```

again and again I got empty result.

I don't have any idea why this simple thing doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
b = foreach a generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'projectVersion:([^\t]*)');
```

You need to use "()" to indicate what you want.

For you case,

```
projectName:test    logType:test    logSource:test  logBody:test
```

b will have a tuple `('test')`